# Python read page from URL? Better documentation?

Tags: python, url, urllib

I'm having quite a bit of trouble with Python's documentation. Is there anything like the Mozilla Developer Network for it?

I'm doing a Python puzzle website and I need to be able to read the content of the page. I saw the following posted on a site:

```
import urllib2

urlStr = 'http://www.python.org/'
try:
  fileHandle = urllib2.urlopen(urlStr)
  str1 = fileHandle.read()
  fileHandle.close()
  print ('-'*50)
  print ('HTML code of URL =', urlStr)
  print ('-'*50)
except IOError:
  print ('Cannot open URL %s for reading' % urlStr)
  str1 = 'error!'

print (str1)
```

It keeps saying that there is no urllib2 module.

The Python documentation says

`The urllib module has been split into parts and renamed in Python 3.0 to urllib.request, urllib.parse, and urllib.error. The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to 3.0. Also note that the urllib.urlopen() function has been removed in Python 3.0 in favor of urllib2.urlopen().`

I tried importing urllib.request too, but it ssays urllib 2 is defined... WTF is going on here?

Version 3.2.2

Comment: Your Python version would be useful at this juncture.

Comment: Updated. Any other documentation for Python than what's given?

Comment: @Walkerneo: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html

Comment: Is this the documentation you're using? http://docs.python.org/py3k/

Comment: Yes and yes. I've been using that. @icktoofay thanks, that helps. I have to do urllib.request.openurl then. Thanks, put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Hey, you actually deleted your answer. I was just kidding though, that's why I didn't accept the other one. Sorry for attempting a sense of humor, I shall not again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you were probably referencing was [the Python 2 documentation for `urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html). The documentation you should probably be using is [the Python 3 documentation for `urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html).

Answer (score 4):

Using [`urllib.request.open()`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.1/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen), as recommended in [Dive into Python 3](http://diveintopython3.org/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#urllib)...

```
Python 3.2.1 (default, Jul 24 2011, 22:21:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib.request
>>> urlStr = 'http://www.python.org/'
>>> fileHandle = urllib.request.urlopen(urlStr)
>>> print(fileHandle.read()[:100])
b'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtm'
```

Comment: Now file fileHandle contains the complete source. How can I use the xpath on fileHandle data to get particular value?

Comment: @DixitSingla: You could use `lxml`, like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11466033/78845