# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I'm currently doing an online Python puzzle series, and I've gotten to a problem where you need to unload a pickled file. I read the documentation on it, but I kept getting

`TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

...so I search on Google and arrive at a question on SO with a similar problem. The answer points to http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle .

I tried the code in the example and I'm getting the same problem? I'm using Python 3.2.2. WTF??

Complete Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\foo.py", line 11, in <module>
    test1()
  File "C:\foo.py", line 9, in test1
    favorite_color = pickle.load( open( "save.p" ) )
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

From the example here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

I have already successfully created the save.p file with the first code example in the tutorial.

Comment: Probably python 2 vs python 3 difference. Can you post a complete traceback?

Comment: I was just clicking the first Google links. I wasn't aware that not only was I reading Python 2 stuff, but that Python 2 and 3 have MAJOR differences... Anyway, where do I find Python 3 stuff?

Comment: Also, that's not my previous question.

Comment: Sorry... wrong link. In [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617661/python-read-page-from-url-better-documentation/7617733#7617733) to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617661/python-read-page-from-url-better-documentation), I linked to "Dive into Python 3". That's well worth a read. The majority of information out there still refers to Python 2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open the pickle file in binary mode: `favorite_color = pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))`.